Increasing or decreasing flow rate
Suppose we have a pipe 20mm in diameter with water flowing through it at a flow rate of 15 liters per minute. The pipe widens at a point in the middle and inside the pipe is an object which fills the pipe but has a number of holes in it which the water can flow through, like a type of mesh. The total cross sectional area of these holes is equal to the cross sectional area of the 20mm diameter section of the pipe. I am assuming that the flow rate through all the holes together is the same as through the pipe - but what about the flow rate through each hole?
If the number of holes is increased, and the total cross sectional area is increased, does that decrease the flow rate inside each hole?

The flow rate through each hole should be equal.
If you increase the number of holes or that is, increasing the cross sectional area,  the flow rate decreases per unit hole as :-
Firstly, the flow rate in that mesh decreases further due to increase in cross sectional area.
Secondly, the number of holes also increase.
So, it's like a fraction, where you have decreased the numerator and increased the denominator, to obtain the final result. So, the fraction will always be smaller than the original fraction. Likewise, the rate of per hole decreases.
